# QWizardPage registerField() for class property not working

Tags: c++, qt, wizard

I have a wizard page where the user can choose a database connection. To represent a database connection i created a class to wrap database information. I want to use the field-mechanism of QWizardPage to make the selected database connection accessible from the outside, but it is not working the way i expected it to work.

Header:

```
Q_PROPERTY(DBConnectionInfo connection READ getConnection NOTIFY connectionChanged)
```

CPP:

```
qRegisterMetaType<DBConnectionInfo>();
registerField("connection*", this, "connection", SIGNAL(connectionChanged(DBConnectionInfo)));
selected_connection = DBConnectionInfo("MyNewName", "MyServer", "MyDB", 3000, "MyUser", "MyPW");
emit connectionChanged(selected_connection);

std::cout << "Value of name: \"" << field("connection").value<DBConnectionInfo>().getName().toStdString() << "\"";
std::cout << "Value of property: \"" << property("connection").value<DBConnectionInfo>().getName().toStdString() << "\"";
```

Result:

```
Value of name: ""
Value of property: "MyNewName"
```

So the property is set up properly, but the value is not accessible through the field-mechanism. Any ideas what i could be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the field-access only works outside of the constructor. When moving the print statements out of the constructor into `initializePage` for example, it will work.

Comment: Working "outside" of the constructor is probably only half of the story. Most likely it works once the event queue has been drained.

Comment: I have no idea what is going on under the hood. There is also no remark in the documentation. I guess you are fine if you just do the field-calls in the `initializePage` method (which is probably the way it was meant to be used in the first place).